# Ao reparar causa erro - 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query' - Aguma Idéia?

Tags: mysql, delphi

Segue o código:

```
ZQuery1.Close;
      ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
      ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SHOW TABLES FROM '+zConnRepara.Database);
      ZQuery1.Open;
      ZQuery1.First;
      Progressbar1.Max := ZQuery1.RecordCount;

      lTemp := '';
      Parametro := '';
      //nomeDoDB'.'db.table := db.db.table
      Parametro := zConnRepara.Database + '.' +
        ZQuery1.FieldByName('Tables_in_' +
          zConnRepara.Database).asString;

      if ZQuery1.RecordCount > 1 then
        ZQuery1.Next;
      //check
      while not ZQuery1.Eof do
      begin
        Parametro := Parametro + ',' + zConnRepara.Database + '.' +
        ZQuery1.FieldByName('Tables_in_' +
        zConnRepara.Database).asString;

        ZQuery1.Next;
      end;
      ZQuery2.Close;
      ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
      ZQuery2.Sql.Text := 'Check table ' + Parametro;
      ZQuery2.Open;
      CloseQuery;

      if ZQuery2.RecordCount > 1 then
        ZQuery2.Next;
      lTemp := '';
      //ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
      //repair
      while not ZQuery2.Eof do
      begin
        try
          status := ZQuery2.FieldByName('Msg_text').AsString;
          if (status <> 'OK') and (status = 'Corrupt') then
          begin
            zConnRepara.Connected := true;
            inc(i);
            ZQuery3.Close;
            ZQuery3.SQL.Clear;
            ZQuery3.SQL.Add('Repair table '+ Parametro);
            ZQuery3.ExecSQL;
            lTemp := lTemp + ',' + ZQuery2.FieldByName(
              'Table').AsString;
            StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Tabela sendo reparada: '+lTemp;
            zConnRepara.Connected := false;
          end;
        except
          on e: Exception do ShowMessage(''+e.Message);
        end;
```

a minha dúvida, é que o código está correto, e mesmo assim dá esse erro, poderiam me ajudar? minha lógica ta correta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua lógica está certa eu não sei, pois não sei o que você quer fazer, mas seu while está num loop infinito, já que você não está dando um zQuery2.Next;.

Acredito que seu loop correto seria:

```
while not ZQuery2.Eof do
  begin
    try
      status := ZQuery2.FieldByName('Msg_text').AsString;
      if (status <> 'OK') and (status = 'Corrupt') then
      begin
        zConnRepara.Connected := true;
        inc(i);
        ZQuery3.Close;
        ZQuery3.SQL.Clear;
        ZQuery3.SQL.Add('Repair table '+ Parametro);
        ZQuery3.ExecSQL;
        lTemp := lTemp + ',' + ZQuery2.FieldByName(
          'Table').AsString;
        StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Tabela sendo reparada: '+lTemp;
        zConnRepara.Connected := false;
      end;
      //Se você não fizer um zQuery2.next aqui você nunca chegará no EOF.
      zQuery2.next;
    except
      on e: Exception do ShowMessage(''+e.Message);
    end;
```

Outra coisa: Não precisa abrir e fechar zConnRepara o tempo todo, basta setar o KeepConnection = false que o componente zQuery vai abrir e fechar pra você.

Outra Outra Coisa: Passe a usar clientDataSet.

**EDIT:**

Se o código realmente está incompleto como mencionado nos comentários, é muito provável que você esteja ficando tempo demais com a mesma conexão aberta fazendo **loops** e **lógicas de negócio**, coisas que **não necessitam** de conexão com o banco. Isso certamente pode causar um *connection Time-out*.

O ideal é recuperar os dados, fechar a conexão, trabalhar com eles em cache e finalmente abrir a conexão, persistir os dados e fechar a conxão. Deixando o *keepConnection = false* te alivia de ficar abrindo e fechando a conexão o tempo todo.

Se mesmo com o *keepconnection = false* o problema persistir então eu creio que exista alguma consulta demorando mais que o time-out de seu banco, deixando apenas duas opções:

1. Rever sua consulta
2. Aumentar o time-out do banco

Comment: Esta utilizando isso aqui `if ZQuery2.RecordCount > 1 then     ZQuery2.Next;` então, o next ta certinho, sobre o ZConnrepara, eu percebi e retirei, vou testar o `KeepConnection`.

Comment: Não cara, olha dentro do seu **while not zQuery2.eof**. Em nenhum momento você dá um zQuery2.next. Vou editar a minha resposta e te mostrar como eu acho que seria.

Comment: Ah sim cara, kkkk, que droga, foi erro meu msm, é que o código não foi completo :/, desculpa ai

Comment: @RamonRuan Editei a resposta considerando que seu while está da forma que postei.